# From April 9, 2020, Can I list user’s spreadsheets in the v3 API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Let me ask you about the following statement on this page.
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/02/sheets-api-migration-update.html

> Starting on April 9, 2020, the spreadsheet and spreadsheets.readonly scopes can no longer be used to list a user’s spreadsheets in the v3 API.

I don't use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets scope in my application.

However, I use the following scopes.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
https://docs.google.com/feeds

And I found the following statement on this page.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
>   which is an alias
>   for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

That page says " the spreadsheet and spreadsheets.readonly scopes", but Is it actually affected if I use another scope?

Comment: I think that if the script uses Sheets API v4, even when the scope of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` is changed to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`, the script works. But if the script uses Sheets API v3, it is required to modify for using v4. About this, I'm not sure about your actual script. I apologize for this. And also, in this case, it is required to reauthorize the scopes. So please be careful this. By the way, I cannot understand about `From April 9, 2020, Can I list user’s spreadsheets in the v3 API?`? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

My application uses Sheets API v3. And I want to update the application to use API v4.
But I have other tasks, I cannot start this task until May.

Google says `On September 30, 2020, the remainder of the v3 API will be turned down.`
If this alone, I didn't think it was a problem. Because I'm in time.

But Google also says `Starting on April 9, 2020, the spreadsheet and spreadsheets.readonly scopes can no longer be used to list a user’s spreadsheets in the v3 API.`

Comment: And there was such a description.
'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds' which is an alias for 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'

My application use 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds' scope.
If my application couldn't get a list at this scope, it would stop working on April 9 before September 30.
If this happens, I will not be in time.

Because of this, I want to know what happens to the Sheets API v3 on April 9.

Did what I wanted to say get across?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want to know what happens to the Sheets API v3 on April 9.`, I have no correct and clear answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you.
I was very happy to hear from you.